# Trying to hide an element by class in JS, but receive a "cannot set property 'class' of undefined" error

Tags: javascript, wordpress, undefined, visibility

I have a function called "hideConstruction()", toggled by the click of a button on my wordpress page. It should hide all elements with the class ".construction", but instead I get the following error:

"Cannot set property 'visibility' of undefined"

This is the code that I put in my wordpress's script.js, enqueued via functions.php:

```
function hideConstruction() {
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName("construction").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Here is the page where this is happening: https://satya-ame-art.com

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Many thanks!

Comment: Use `document.querySelector(".construction").style.visibility` if you only have one

Comment: Thank you for your help! I wouldn't consider this a duplicate though, as the previous answer only treated cases with one element per CSS class. As I had several elements under the same CSS class that I wanted to affect, Shubham Singh's answer of adding [0], [1], [2]... was unique, as far as I know.

Comment: The dupe is the fact you need to handle a collection. Whether it’s 1,2 or many - it is really very basic stuff easily found in the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you run this in console  `document.getElementsByClassName("construction")` it gives two elements so if you want to hide first element then use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("construction")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
```

and for second element hide use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("construction")[1].style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Comment: Perfect!! I would have spent a week trying to figure that out by myself. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**document.getElementsByClassname** returns an array of HTMLCollection of found elements.

The correct way of implementing this would be

```
function hideConstruction() {
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName("construction")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Thanks!!